# EF 4.1 Code First Raw SQL

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I would like to return entities using RAW SQL, so I have the following code which returns a set of Entities:

```
var rawSql = "exec spFindStories @pattern, @page, @pageSize"; 

            // use raw SQL because SP is needed
            // results are not tracked.
            var stories = context.Database.SqlQuery<Story>(rawSql, 
                new SqlParameter("@pattern", pattern),
                new SqlParameter("@page", page),
                new SqlParameter("@pageSize", pageSize)                
               ).ToList();
```

Now for each one of these stories, I need to load their related Tags. It seems that CF does not load related entities returned in the results.   How can I achieve this ??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not add it as a function import and specify what it's returning as the entity you expect?